# Using REST Api to Create a Project on DevOps

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to create a new project on DevOps using the REST Api in Blazor Webassembly C#.

Everything works fine so far, but it doesn't enter the last line in my function `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Operations.Operation operation = await operationsHttpClient.GetOperation(resultId);`
It is also not throwing any error. PAT and URI are correct. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
   public async Task PushProjectToDevOps(string pat, ProjectDTO project)
    {
        TeamProject teamProject = new();
        teamProject.Name = project.Name;
        teamProject.Description = project.Description;
        VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", pat);
        var connection = new VssConnection(uri, credentials);

        OperationsHttpClient operationsHttpClient = connection.GetClient<OperationsHttpClient>();

        using (ProjectHttpClient projectHttpClient = new ProjectHttpClient(uri, credentials))
        {
            var resultId = projectHttpClient.QueueCreateProject(teamProject).Result.Id;

            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Operations.Operation operation = await operationsHttpClient.GetOperation(resultId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you fully-qualifying the `Operation` type, when you could simply use a namespace?

Comment: And what did you mean by "it doesn't enter the last line in my function?"  Did you set a breakpoint there, and it never hit it?

Comment: 1. Because it threw an ambigous reference.
2. Exactly. It moved to the line with var resultId and then it breaks and goes back to my controller where I called the function.

Comment: I would first verify that it's producing the expected results before relying on breakpoints to verify program flow.  `async` operations can sometimes produce unexpected and counter-intuitive debugger behavior.

Comment: One way you can verify that the program flow is correct is by putting your breakpoint on the ending brace of that `using` statement instead of trying to single-step through your `async` code.